# npm run scripts runs infinite amounts of time

Tags: npm, node-sass, postcss

I have scss files which I want to convert to css then run autoprefixer, then minify the whole thing.

I came to this code:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.2",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^7.0.23",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "watch": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass -o www/css src/scss",
    "prefix": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' < www/css/websiteStyles.css | postcss --use cssnano > www/css/websiteStyles.min.css",
    "dev": "npm-run-all scss prefix",
    "watch" : "watch 'npm run dev'"
  },
```

When I run `npm run watch` the script runs infinitely. I don't change anything but the script runs and runs and then runs ageain. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Writing all those files *is* changing something.